# Producing an output box from a form

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>CT Traders</title>
<style>
fieldset    {width:40%; margin:0px 0px 10px 1%;}
legend      {padding:2px; text-indent:5px;}
h2, p       {margin-left: 1%;} 
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] 
            {display:inline; float:none;}
</style>
<script>
 //suggested logic for the validateInput() function
function validateInputs() 
{
//check payment method
var methodChecked = false;
for (var i=0; i <document.frmCustOrders.class.length;i++)
{
    if (document.frmCustOrders.class[i].checked ==true)
    {
        classChecked = true;
        vClass = document.frmCustOrders.class[i].value;
    }

}

//check customer index value
var customerIndex = document.getElementById("customer").value;

//retrieve order quantity
var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;

//validate form data
if (customerIndex == -1) //validate customer
{
    alert("Please select a customer.")

    return false;
}
else if () //validate qty
{

}
else if (fsClassChecked == false) //validate payment method
{
    alert("Please select a payment method.")
    return false;
}
else //output
{
    orderEntries = customer+ "\n"+ qty+ "\n"+vClass;
    alert(orderEntries);
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Customer Order</h2>
<form name="frmCustOrders" id="frmCustOrders"
onsubmit="return validateInputs();" action="">

<fieldset id="fsCustomer">
<legend>Customer List</legend>
<select name="customer" id="customer" size="3"> 
    <option>107 Paula Harris</option>
    <option>232 Mitch Edwards</option>
    <option>229 BTC</option>
</select>
</fieldset>

<p> 
<label for="qty">Order Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" />
</p>

<fieldset id="fsClass">
<legend>Payment Method</legend> 
<input type="radio" name="method" id="check" value="check" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Check<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="method" id="creditCard" value="credit card" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Credit Card<br />
<input type="radio" name="method" id="debitCard" value="debit card" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Debit Card
</fieldset>
<p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having issues getting an output box that retrieves the selections on the form.
  Also, in one of my if statements I'm assigned to check if the value is between 1 and 999 but I'm drawing a total blank on this. I'm new to coding (Javascript) and this is my first class. Any help with getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code

Redundant `else if ()`

`fsClassChecked` variable not declared.

Redundant class when iterate elements `document.frmCustOrders.class`

Use wrong variable `customer` should be `customerIndex`

Wrong condition `(customerIndex == -1)` change to `(customerIndex == "")`

```js
//suggested logic for the validateInput() function
function validateInputs() 
{
//check payment method
var methodChecked = false;
var fsClassChecked = false;
for (var i=0; i <document.frmCustOrders.length;i++)
{
    if (document.frmCustOrders[i].checked ==true)
    {
        fsClassChecked = true;
        vClass = document.frmCustOrders[i].value;
    }

}

//check customer index value
var customerIndex = document.getElementById("customer").value;

//retrieve order quantity
var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;

//validate form data
if (customerIndex == "") //validate customer
{
    alert("Please select a customer.")

    return false;
}
else if(qty == "" || qty < 1 || qty > 999){
alert("Please enter qty 1-999.")

    return false;
}
else if (fsClassChecked == false) //validate payment method
{
    alert("Please select a payment method.")
    return false;
}
else //output
{
    orderEntries = customerIndex + "\n"+ qty+ "\n"+vClass;
    alert(orderEntries);
    return false;
}

return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>CT Traders</title>
<style>
fieldset    {width:40%; margin:0px 0px 10px 1%;}
legend      {padding:2px; text-indent:5px;}
h2, p       {margin-left: 1%;} 
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] 
            {display:inline; float:none;}
</style>
<script>
 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Customer Order</h2>
<form name="frmCustOrders" id="frmCustOrders"
onsubmit="return validateInputs();" action="#">

<fieldset id="fsCustomer">
<legend>Customer List</legend>
<select name="customer" id="customer" size="3"> 
    <option>107 Paula Harris</option>
    <option>232 Mitch Edwards</option>
    <option>229 BTC</option>
</select>
</fieldset>

<p> 
<label for="qty">Order Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" />
</p>

<fieldset id="fsClass">
<legend>Payment Method</legend> 
<input type="radio" name="method" id="check" value="check" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Check<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="method" id="creditCard" value="credit card" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Credit Card<br />
<input type="radio" name="method" id="debitCard" value="debit card" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Debit Card
</fieldset>
<p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if a customer isn't selected or quantity isn't entered, there should be an alert box prompting the user to select the customer or enter the quantity. I forgot to add that part. I also need to have an IF statement that checks the order quantity is between 1 and 999.

Comment: The alert for no quantity entered and alert for payment method is working. If there's no customer selected there's no alert happening. Can you help me with that? Also I need the code to validate the quantity is between 1-999.

Comment: I update for check qty 1-999, why payment method not work, it still show?

Comment: The payment method alert box works if not selected.

Comment: I can't get the alert box to work if a customer isn't selected.